# After connected to Mac dosen't show Main.storyboard

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I successfully connected to the Mac but when I open Main.storyboard show progress bar (Starting Designer Agent) and cannot be displayed design.

[image]

In addition , I update Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 and Mac to the latest version.

Comment: From your screenshot it seems that you have limited connectivity (connectivity indicator is orange). Try connecting again and or restart visual studio. Once the connectivity indicator is green if problem persist try reopening storyboard in visual studio..

Comment: That's right but when I have full connectivity (connectivity indicator is green) and restart visual studio and Mac then try reopening storyboard in visual studio.unfortunately , again I have same problem.

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem?
I am much time involved in the problem...
Please , help me.